# WooCommerce: list users without a purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to clean up the user database and remove accounts that haven't made a purchase. So far I only found solutions to list users that purchased an item. How to do the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the users with no orders:

```
$all_users = get_users();

        if ( !empty( $all_users ) ) {
            $no_order_user_list = [];
            foreach($all_users as $user) {
                if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
                    continue;
                $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
                     'numberposts' => -1,
                     'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                     'meta_value'  => $user->ID,
                     'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
                     'post_status' => array('wc-pending', 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed') //array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()),
                ));

                if( count( $customer_orders ) == 0 ) {
                    $no_order_user_list [] = $user;
                }
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($no_order_user_list);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Accept my answer and up vote if it is solved your problem.